# comparing nested lists and editing

Tags: python, nested-lists

Sorry if this sounds like a silly question but this problem has gotten me really confused. I'm fairly new to python, so maybe I'm missing something. I did some research but haven't gotten too far. Here goes:

I'm going to use a simple example that makes the question clearer, my data is different but the format and required action is the same. We have a database of people and the pizzas they eat (and some other data). Our database however has multiple entries of the same people with different pizzas (because we combined data gotten from different pizzerias).

example dataset:

> `allData = [['joe','32', 'pepperoni,cheese'],['marc','24','cheese'],['jill','27','veggie supreme, cheese'],['joe','32','pepperoni,veggie supreme']['marc','25','cheese,chicken supreme']]`

Few things we notice and rules I want to follow:

- names can appear multiple times though in this specific case we KNOW that any entries with the same name is the same person.
- the age can be different for the same person in different entries, so we just pick the first age we encountered of the person and use it. example `marc`'s age is `24` and we ignore the `25` from the second entry

I want to edit the data so that a person's name only appears ONCE, and the pizzas he eats is a unique set from all entries with the same name. As mentioned before the age is just the first one encountered. Therefore, i'd want the final data to look like this:

> `fixedData = [['joe','32','pepperoni,cheese,veggie supreme'],['marc','24','cheese,chicken supreme'],['jill','27','veggie supreme, cheese']]`

I'm thinking something on the lines of:

```
fixedData = []
for i in allData:
    if i[0] not in fixedData[0]:    
        fixedData.append[i]
    else:
        fixedData[i[-1]]=set(fixedData[i[-1]],i[-1])
```

I know I'm making several mistakes. could you please please point me towards the right direction?

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since names are unique, it makes sense to use them as keys in a dict, where the name is the key. This will be much more appropriate in your case:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in allData:
    if i[0] in d:
        d[i[0]][-1] = list(set(d[i[0]][-1] + (i[-1].split(','))))
    else:
        d[i[0]] = [i[1],i[2].split(',')]


>>> d
   {'jill': ['27', ['veggie supreme', ' cheese']], 'joe': ['32', ['pepperoni', 'cheese', 'pepperoni', 'veggie supreme']], 'marc': ['24', ['cheese', 'cheese', 'chicken supreme']]}
```

Comment: you welcome. Alas, I have hit 3333 rep points... Who would upvote me now and destroy this unique number..

Answer (score 0):

In cases like yours i like to use defaultdict. I really hate the guesswork that comes with list indexes.

```
from collections import defaultdict

allData = [['joe', '32', 'pepperoni,cheese'],
           ['marc', '24', 'cheese'],
           ['jill', '27', 'veggie supreme, cheese'],
           ['joe', '32', 'pepperoni,veggie supreme'],
           ['marc', '25', 'cheese,chicken supreme']]

d = defaultdict(dict)
for name, age, pizzas in allData:
    d[name].setdefault('age', age)
    d[name].setdefault('pizzas', set())
    d[name]['pizzas'] |= set(pizzas.split(','))
```

Notice the usage of [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set the first age value we encounter. It also enables the use of set union to get the unique pizzas.